# Android - printable, filename friendly way of getting time&date?

Tags: android, file, time, logging

I am using `android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date())` to get time & date. The problem is it isn't formated in a way that I can use it as part of a filename - I am creating log files, and I need the format of like 20111123_123412 or something that is possible to directly use as part of a file name. How do I get that easily from Android?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss", new java.util.Date());
```

**EDIT:**

I used Something like,

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
Date date = new Date();
String fileName = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: It seems to give me 'hours' as 0-11 (pm/am). I want 0-23 instead. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace colons in your date format: `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` → `"yyyy-MM-dd_hh.mm.ss"`